Point constraints for mgcv smooths
This question has been raised in the following previous post, but I doubt the answer given there is satisfactory: Constaint on te() tensor product gam mgcv
For mgcv-users the question is: How does one correctly implement boundary conditions for smooths in the mgcv-package, when these have been modified using the d-keyword?
Here are some examples to elaborate on the question and show what I have tried so far
Example 1:
model <- mgcv::bam(Y ~ s(x, y, k = 500, pc = c(0, 0)) +
                       s(z, k = 5, pc = 0) +
                       ti(x, y, z, d = c(2,1), k = c(20, 5), pc = c(0, 0, 0)),
                   data = data,
                   family = tw(link=log),
                   method = "fREML")

Example 2:
model <- mgcv::bam(Y ~ s(x, y, k = 500, pc = c(0, 0)) +
                       s(z, k = 5, pc = 0) +
                       ti(x, y, z, d = c(2,1), k = c(20, 5), pc = list(c(0, 0), c(0)),
                   data = data,
                   family = tw(link=log),
                   method = "fREML")

Example 3:
model <- mgcv::bam(Y ~ s(x, y, k = 500, pc = c(0, 0)) +
                       s(z, k = 5, pc = 0) +
                       ti(x, y, z, d = c(2,1), k = c(20, 5), pc = list(list(0, 0), list(0)),
                   data = data,
                   family = tw(link=log),
                   method = "fREML")

Example 4:
model <- mgcv::bam(Y ~ s(x, y, k = 500, pc = c(0, 0)) +
                       s(z, k = 5, pc = 0) +
                       ti(x, y, z, d = c(2,1), k = c(20, 5), pc = list(0,0,0),
                   data = data,
                   family = tw(link=log),
                   method = "fREML")

.. But they all result in the error
Error in if (length(pc) < d) stop("supply a value for each variable for a point constraint") :  the condition has length > 1

Closer inspection shows that it has to do with the specication of d as d=c(2,1). A solution is there to switch to d = 3. Indeed, this is what is suggested in the previous post. This is however not satisfactory as I would like to exploit the isotropy in the first two coordinates.

This is almost certainly a bug; d is a length m vector where m is the number of margins and hence length(pc) < d will result in a length m logical vector, which now, with modern R versions, will raise an error. You should email Simon at the address in the Maintainer field of the DESCRIPTION (or see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html ). This has nothing to do with d in your examples; it fails with a simpler te(x,z, pc = list(x = 0, z = 0)) call too. I haven't debugged any further to see if any of your egs work if we get past the erroneous if() check
